# How to create spring maven project in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create spring + maven project in IntelliJ IDEA.
I've read [these official wiki](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON), but when I finish steps, there is no maven in my project.
I've tried to add it with my hands, but it seems, that I have hands not so good enough :(, because maven dependencies, lib folder and classes, that I want to use live their own lives (dependencies aren't in lib folder and I try to type classes from dependencies, there is no auto-complete).
Does anyone has step-by-step guide or link?

Answer (score 25):

Go to https://start.spring.io and let the Initializr generate a Maven project for you with the desired dependencies.

You will get a zip file which you can then unpack in your dev folder.

Then open Intellij and select  File | New | Project from Existing Sources. (Or Import Project from the welcome screen).

Select your unzipped folder, and then follow the wizard, selecting Maven when you are prompted to.

See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/importing-project-from-maven-model.html

Comment: This https://start.spring.io is for Spring boot based applications only right?

Comment: @MenukaIshan yes you are right.

Comment: what dev folder you are refering to? can i extract it anywhere?

Comment: @JayDangar yes, anywhere you like.

Comment: thanks bro this answer really helped me out. upvoted and should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

First create a spring project by going to File->New->Project and select spring. It will create a spring project. Then to add maven support, you can right click on the project and select "Add Framework Support". It will give you a pop up window, and from that select "maven".

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you looking for?

> **Create new project File > New > Project**
>
> - Click Maven on the left hand side of the new project dialog
> - Check Create from archetype
> - Click the Add Archetype button
> - Set Group Id to pl.codeleak
> - Set Artifact Id to spring-mvc-quickstart
> - Set Version to 1.0.0
> - Set Repository to http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype
> - Click next and create the project

Refer below link for more.

https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

**But** I would refer the classic way. Generate the maven project using arch-type and import the maven project to the Intellij Then add the spring maven dependencies to the pom.xml. It's clear

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want to create **Spring-boot with Maven**: Most use Spring Initilzr.

   - **Use either website: https://start.spring.io/ - you will get packaged stuff - best way**
   - Alternatively In IntelliJ Ultimate Edition (personally best tool): File > New > Project... > Spring Initilzr
   - Finally you can create Maven on your own + add POM.xml with spring-boot dependency
2. If you want to create **Spring non-boot with Maven** from scratch:

   - Just simply File > New > Project... > Maven ... [any archetype]
   - Edit pom.xml so it has SPring dependencies in it:

In this case (**the harder way**)- for Spring Testing start from POM.xml: 
[ entire code + whole intelliJ dump here: https://github.com/wkaczurba/stackoverflow/tree/springmaveninintellij ]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>someartifact</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test-related stuff -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`
Then you can create your first test, e.g.:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
public class WhateverTest {

    @Autowired
    YourInterface objectUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertTrue(objectUnderTest.func());
    }
}
```

And your config + interface + bean:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import com.stackoverflow.YourInterface;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="com.stackoverflow")
public class AppConfig {
    // Add whatever is needed.
}
```

Interface:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface YourInterface {
    public boolean func();
}
```

And Implementation:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class YourInterfaceImpl implements YourInterface {

    public boolean func() {
        System.out.println("func called..."); // Always use logger in real world...
        return true;
    }
}
```

To run:

1. Run: `mvn clean test`
2. Or create in IntelliJ configuration for running the JUnit test and run.

Comment: @Configuration(classes={ whatever.class }) Not compiling at this line

Comment: @Kuldeep Yadav - you had to specify your config class there. I updated the code so it contains Configuration class and provided link to GITHUB so you know where to look for it.